# I'm unable to get the date to equal my string in my Jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var currDay = date.getDate();
                var currMonth = date.getMonth();
                var currYear = date.getFullYear();

                var fullDate = currMonth + '/' + currDay + '/' + currYear;

                fullDate = fullDate.toString();

if(fullDate == special_dates[b][4]){

            return[false];
}
```

I'm using the jquery ui datepicker. special_dates is my array with the date as a string like 12/30/2010

fullDate and special_dates are working when I alert it, so I'm not sure what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It might be as simple as this.  `return[false];` looks wrong.  Try changing this:

```
if(fullDate == special_dates[b][4]){

            return[false];
}
```

to

```
if(fullDate == special_dates[b][4]){
    return false;
}
```

or better yet (if there is no other logic needed):

```
return fullDate == special_dates[b][4];
```

Comment: return [false]; is not invalid but, rather, is an array literal containing a boolean false as the only element. This will be treated as true where a boolean is expected. Probably not what @Adam wanted.

Comment: @chuck I originally said "looks wrong," then edited it to "is invalid."  Just rolled it back.  ;)

Comment: i got it from an example... it seems to work though; the false part. In any case the if statement isn't firing even though it should be. I put an alert in there and nothing.

Comment: So you're saying the problem is here ? `fullDate == special_dates[b][4]`

Comment: it appears so. in fact return false and return true dont work. only [false] ad [true]. Must be a jquery datepicker thing.